# Reduce the data based on version

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have complex logic which I am struggling to write it , I am not sure if I can write it in single query or I need to write a function. I don't want to loop record by record to achieve as it affects the performance.

**Requirement :** I need to reduce the source table based on the version for each ID and adjust the DATE as well.  Check the version 1 then bring it to output ,check version 2 if the AT1 != AT2 then bring it to output but make the previous version inactive and adjust the date of version 1 also.

**Source Table :**

[image]

**Output :**

[image]

SQL I tried but I am not able to proceed further as it complex to incorporate all the logic. Can you please guide.

```
 with history as (SELECT ID,VERSION,FROM ,TO,AT1,AT2 FROM hrhistory),
      prev as (SELECT *, lead(FROM) over(partition by ID order by version ) new_fromm
                       ,lead(To) over (partition by ID order by version ) new_to
                        FROM hrhistory
               where at1!=at2)
               
               select * from prev
     SELECT a.*
     FROM history a LEFT OUTER JOIN prev b
     ON a.ID=b.ID
     WHERE b.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: The version goes from `L1/L1` to `L1/L2`, will it ever go back to `L1/L1` at a later date?

Comment: Yes it can go back to L1 L1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use:

```sql
SELECT id,
       "FROM",
       COALESCE( LEAST( next_from, "TO" ), "TO" ) AS "TO",
       at1,
       at2,
       NVL2( next_from, 'inactive', 'active' ) AS active
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         LEAD( "FROM" ) OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY mn) AS next_from
  FROM   table_name
  MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
    PARTITION BY id
    ORDER     BY "FROM", "TO"
    MEASURES
      MATCH_NUMBER() AS mn,
      FIRST( same_at."FROM" ) AS "FROM",
      MAX( same_at."TO" ) AS "TO",
      FIRST( at1 ) AS at1,
      FIRST( at2 ) AS at2
    ONE ROW PER MATCH
    PATTERN ( same_at+ )
    DEFINE same_at AS (
          FIRST(at1) = at1
      AND FIRST(at2) = at2
    )
  ) t
)
```

Before that, you can use:

```sql
SELECT id,
       MIN( "FROM" ) AS "FROM",
       COALESCE(
         LEAST(
           MAX( next_from ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY "FROM", "TO" ),
           MAX( "TO" )
         ),
         MAX( "TO" )
       ) AS "TO",
       MIN( at1 ) AS at1,
       MIN( at2 ) AS at2,
       NVL2(
         MAX( next_from ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY "FROM", "TO" ),
         'inactive',
         'active'
       ) AS active
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         SUM( has_changed_group ) OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY "FROM", "TO" )
           AS grp
  FROM   (
    SELECT t.*,
           CASE
           WHEN at1 = LAG( at1 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY "FROM", "TO" )
           AND  at2 = LAG( at2 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY "FROM", "TO" )
           THEN 0
           ELSE 1
           END AS has_changed_group,
           LEAD( "FROM" ) OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY "FROM", "TO" )
             AS next_from
    FROM   table_name t
  ) t
)
GROUP BY id, grp
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, version, "FROM", "TO", at1, at2 ) AS
SELECT 1, 1, DATE '2020-01-01', DATE '2020-01-05', 'L1', 'L1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2, DATE '2020-01-03', DATE '2020-01-10', 'L1', 'L2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 3, DATE '2020-01-05', DATE '2020-01-15', 'L1', 'L2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 3, DATE '2020-01-10', DATE '2020-01-20', 'L1', 'L1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, DATE '2020-01-01', DATE '2020-01-10', 'L1', 'L3' FROM DUAL;
```

Then both queries output:

> ```
> ID | FROM                | TO                  | AT1 | AT2 | ACTIVE  
> -: | :------------------ | :------------------ | :-- | :-- | :-------
>  1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 2020-01-03 00:00:00 | L1  | L1  | inactive
>  1 | 2020-01-03 00:00:00 | 2020-01-10 00:00:00 | L1  | L2  | inactive
>  1 | 2020-01-10 00:00:00 | 2020-01-20 00:00:00 | L1  | L1  | active  
>  2 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 2020-01-10 00:00:00 | L1  | L3  | active
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f49919ae4e4bd3703804c80af67f6d4f)*

Comment: Thank you for the reply . We are in 11g :( . Is there a way to achieve this in 11g

Comment: @Satheesh Updated for earlier Oracle versions.

Comment: You are awesome :) Thank you much